# Counting Islands In Matrix Of Boolean

Tags: python, beginner, matrix

Code objective: Read a txt file, parse it into a matrix and count (and also print) the number of unique "islands" in the map formed by the matrix.

**0** = Sea;
**1** = Land;
Islands are orthogonal groups of land.

testfile.txt :

```
5 9
00000
00010
10000
01101
10000
00100
01001
10010
01101
```

Python code:

```
# Reads the file and creates the matrix map.
with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    w = int(f.read(1))
    f.read(1)
    h = int(f.read(1))
    f.read(1)
    map = [[2 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            map[y][x] = int(f.read(1))
        f.read(1)

# Swipes the matrix map after NEW land chunks.
def swipe():
    counter = 0
    for x in range(h):
        for y in range(w):
            if map[x][y] == 1:
                counter += 1
                landInSight(map, x, y, 99)
    print(counter)

# Recursive function to hide any land attached to a chunk already swiped.
def landInSight(m, h, w, c):
    if m[h][w] == 1:
        m[h][w] = c
        if w < len(m[0]) - 1: landInSight(m, h, w + 1, c)
        if h < len(m) - 1: landInSight(m, h + 1, w, c)
        if w > 0: landInSight(m, h, w - 1, c)
        if h > 0: landInSight(m, h - 1, w, c)

# Calls the swipe function.
swipe()
```

It is a very simple code, but I took way too long coding it. This is my first "program" using Python and although it works, it seems too rough. I am looking for any constructive inputs from Python people.

Comment: Can you make more clear definition of an island? Imagine you have diagonal matrix - it's one island or it's equal to the matrix dimension?

Comment: @pgs: The post says "islands are orthogonal groups of land". This seems clear to me (and it corresponds to the code).

Comment: @pgs: As Gareth pointed out two "lands" will be considered from the same island only if they are touching in an orthogonal relation a diagonal would result in different islands unless there is another (or more) land units forming an orthogonal connection between those.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your solution for this task looks pretty elegant, from my point of view. I would just provide minor comments to optimize this code.

---

Your input data is a boolean matrix, so instead of keeping every value as a byte you can use just one bit. For that purpose you can use [bitarray module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/).

---

Another point, that you are loading whole matrix to the memory. It can be too expensive in certain circumstances. I can suggest one stream-based solution which will calculate a number of islands in dynamic manner. This method was discussed [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74797/counting-islands-in-boolean-matrices/74819).

Comment: You code doesn't seem to be correct. It prints `0` for a `1x1` matrix consisting of one element `1`, while the correct answer is `1`.

Comment: @kraskevich: yes, I agree. It was one misspelling `b0 = count_continuous_block(s1)` instead of `b0 = count_continuous_block(s0)`. I changed it. Thank you!

Comment: If the input is an arbitrary 0-1 matrix, your code still doesn't always work. It prints `0` for the matrix `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1,1, 1]]`, but there's clearly 1 connected component.

Comment: @kraskevich: I guess I found one stream-like solution with [cs help](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74797/counting-islands-in-matrix-of-boolean/74819#) but I would like to implement in c instead of python.

Answer (score 1):

You can make reading the input more concise and robust:

```
 def read_matrix(inp_file):
        """
        Reads the matrix from the input file and returns the number of rows, the number 
        of columns and the matrix itself as a list of lists of ints 
        """
        # reads the first line, splits it and parses the parts as integers
        w, h = map(int, inp_file.readline().strip().split())
        # converts the rest of the lines in the input to lists of integers
        field = [list(map(int, line.strip())) for line in inp_file]
        return h, w, field
```

This way it will work properly, even if one of the dimensions is larger than  `9`.

It's also common for a name of a function to be a verb. For instance, `landInSight` sounds a little bit wierd. I'd call it `traverse_matrix` or `flood_fill_matrix` or something like that.

The fact that your `landInSight` function is recursive can cause issues for larger inputs (namely, a stack overflow error). You can make it non-recursive by using a stack (implemented with a standard `list`) and a loop.

Comment: Thank you for the input, your parse is much more elegant than mine and also corrected a problem that I hadn't stumbled on yet (when the number of rows or columns is greater than nine). But, since the reader became a method, is there a way to pass it directly to the new swipe method? In other words, can i turn this two lines: `h, w, f = read_matrix(inp_file)` and `swipe(h, w, f)` into one?

Comment: @BernardoAraujo You can, but I don't think it's a good idea. These functions do different  things.

Comment: @BernardoAraujo I think [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) is what you are looking for: `swipe(*read_matrix(inp_file))`